# How do I write this For loop in Verilog

Tags: verilog

So, I have this error while writing a Verilog file and since I haven't used FOR loops so far I don't really know how to solve this.

Here is the portion of the code:

```
for(counter=0;counter=counter+25000000;counter=counter+1)
begin
    out_leds<=3'b111;
end
```

Here are the errors:

> Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at LEDS.v(20) near text "="
>
> Error (10170): Verilog HDL syntax error at LEDS.v(20) near text ")";
>   expecting ";"

Comment: I have the feeling that even if you get a correct answer to your question, the root of the problem won't be solved until you realise that Verilog is not about sequential processing, but circuit description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for condition has not a comparator. You must write `for(counter=0; counter == counter+...`.

`counter = counter + 25000000` is an assignment of the new value to counter.

`counter == counter + 25000000` is a statement that checks, if counter is the same as counter+25000000`

But also this is a infinite loop, as counter is never equal to counter+25000000.

You can create a variable `x = counter + 25000000` and then use this variable in your loop: `for(counter=0; counter==x; counter=counter+1)`

See e.g. [here](http://electrosofts.com/verilog/loop_statements.html)